# Python open(file) function not printing the content of the file

Tags: python

To be more precise, when trying to print the content of the .txt file into the terminal, all I get is "Process finished with exit code 0".
Exact code:

```
file = open("vits.txt", "r")
print(file.read())
```

I do have the .txt file inside the directory too; the IDE I use autofills the file name for me.

Comment: You must not be looking in the right place, because that's exactly how it is done.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: The file exists, but is empty.

Comment: Use the full file path instead of just its name. Your current working directory could be in the wrong place.

Comment: _I do have the .txt file inside the directory too_ What do you mean by "the directory"?  Do you mean "the same directory as the python script file"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that syntax use this:

```
with open("vits.txt", "r") as file:
    print(file.readlines())
```